# differentiable mapping between surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be surfaces, and $f: M\rightarrow N$ a differentiable and bijective map

(a) Can you ensure that f is a diffeomorphism?

(b) Suppose further that the map $T_{p}f:T_{M}\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ is an isomorphism for each $p\in M$, can you ensure that a diffeomorphism?

in (a) i think that is false, but I try to make a example, but the differentiability of the inverse is always hard

Comment: (a) is false for curves, just take $M$ and $N$ to be the real line.  The product of this map with the identity on the real line gives you an example for surfaces.  For (b) look at the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (a) let $M = N = \mathbb{R}^2$ with standard coordinates $(x,y)$ for $M$ and $(u,v)$ for $N$. Let $f$ be:
$$ f(x,y) = (x^3,y) $$

Clearly $f$ is bijective and differentiable. But the inverse map
$$ g(u,v) = (\sqrt[3]{u},v) $$
is not differentiable when $u = 0$.

---

For (b) by the inverse function theorem $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Then since it is bijective it is a diffeomorphism.